# Resume sub activities after Home key

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, back-stack, android-homebutton

My problem is that `onStart`, `onResume`, `onRestoreInstanceState` etc are *not* called by the system after using the home key and restart. The situation is as follows,

1. Activity is a splash screen during the first 3 seconds ,
2. Which then starts another activity with the Main screen (with View and buttons),
3. One of these buttons starts an activity with a gridview (game levels),
4. From where I start an activity with the actual game level.

All this works fine, then in the 4th activity I press Home, do some stuff,
then long-press Home again, select my app's icon to restart.

The system takes me back directly to the 3rd activity (not the 4th). But what is even worse is this 3rd activity gets no callback whatsoever from the system that it restarted!

How can this be?

Comment: Loads of reasons. The first that pops to mind is that you finished() the forth activity on exit. What kind of callback is the 3rd Activity expecting?

Comment: well... I would say onResume(), onStart() as documented! that would be sufficient to restore the 4th activity. And you are right : the fourth activity is finish()-ed indeed. One problem solved already! Thx AedonEtLIRA!